# Fatal Exception crash in IOS12.5.x device

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-foundation

I am seeing this crash in crashlytics, not able to reproduce but trying to reproduce in logs.Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xb82e03580e4e92a0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}

```
    0 CoreFoundation 0x119180 __exceptionPreprocess
    1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x59f8 objc_exception_throw
    2 CoreFoundation 0x3288c +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
    3 Foundation 0x8ab38 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
    4 UIKitCore 0x1e3d80 __45-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke
    5 UIKitCore 0x1e3578 -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]
    6 UIKitCore 0x1b785c -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
    7 UIKitCore 0xd54170 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
    8 QuartzCore 0x13ec60 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
    9 QuartzCore 0x143c08 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
    10 UIKitCore 0xd401a4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded]
    11 UIKitCore 0xd468f0 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
    12 UIKitCore 0xadb814 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
    13 UIKitCore 0xadbb18 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:]
    14 UIKitCore 0xaa8294 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:]
    15 UIKitCore 0xac5640 -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
    16 UIKitCore 0xd54170 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
    17 QuartzCore 0x13ec60 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
    18 QuartzCore 0x143c08 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
    19 QuartzCore 0xa63e4 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
    20 QuartzCore 0xd4620 CA::Transaction::commit()
    21 QuartzCore 0xd515c CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
    22 CoreFoundation 0xaa4fc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
    23 CoreFoundation 0xa5224 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
    24 CoreFoundation 0xa57a0 __CFRunLoopRun
    25 CoreFoundation 0xa4fb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    26 GraphicsServices 0xa79c GSEventRunModal
    27 UIKitCore 0x8bcc38 UIApplicationMain
    28 Project_Name 0x5bf4 main + 25 (AppDelegate.swift:25)
    29 libdyld.dylib 0x18e0 start
```

Comment: Please provide some more context

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.